# php split integer into smaller parts

Tags: php, barcode

i'm working on a project that will need to have everything shown with barcodes, so I've generated 7 numbers for EAN8 algorithm and now have to get these 7 numbers seperately, right now i'm using for the generation

```
$codeint = mt_rand(1000000, 9999999);
```

and I need to get this 7 numbers each seperately so I can calculate the checksum for EAN8, how can i split this integer to 7 parts, for example

```
12345678 to 
arr[0]=1
arr[1]=2
arr[2]=3
arr[3]=4
arr[4]=5
arr[5]=6
arr[6]=7
```

any help would be appreciated..

also I think that I'm becoming crazy :D because I already tried most of the solutions you gave me here before and something is not working like it should work, for example:

```
$codeint = mt_rand(1000000, 9999999);
echo $codeint."c</br>";
echo $codeint[1];
echo $codeint[2];
echo $codeint[3];
```

gives me :

```
9082573c
empty row
empty row
empty row


solved! $codeint = (string)(mt_rand(1000000, 9999999));
```

Comment: if `mt_rand()` returns 1 or an integer with less that 7 digits?

Comment: [`str_split($codeint)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) is enought?

Comment: You can access like $codeint[0], $codeint[1] directly without any extra efforts.

Comment: just changed to mt_rand :) the first one was just for testing.

Comment: if variable is a string or integer you can access its fields 1 by one usign its position $number[0] = first symbol from your string , $number[1] second and etc..

Comment: i've tried something like this before and i've updated the question now, something is not working like it should :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to do this, one of which is reasonably unique to PHP:

1) In PHP, you can treat an integer value as a string and then index into the individual digits:

```
$digits = "$codeint";
// access a digit using intval($digits[3])
```

2) However, the much more elegant way is to use actual integer division and a little knowledge about mathematical identities of digits, namely in a number `123`, each place value is composed of ascending powers of 10, i.e.: `1 * 10^2 + 2 * 10^1 + 3 * 10^0`.

Consequently, dividing by powers of 10 will permit you to access each digit in turn.

Comment: nice, +1, potentially casting to a string could have worked too, `(string)$codeint`.

Comment: When did PHP get proper casts? It's been a while since I've touched it :p

Comment: Perhaps overly complex in this case, but I do love the mathematical solution :) +1

Comment: `$codeint=(string)intval(sprintf("%0d",mt_rand(1,9999999)));` then `echo $codeint[0];`. If the OP wants to use the splice of the number as an integer, then he can just cast it back like `echo (int)$codeint[0];`.

Comment: i've tried something like this before and i've updated the question now, something is not working like it should :/

Answer (score 6):

Try to use [`str_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) function:

```
$var = 1234567;
print_r(str_split($var));
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 6
    [6] => 7
)
```

Comment: i've updated the question now, something is not working like it should :/

Answer (score 1):

You can divide them in loop by 10:

```
12345678 is 8*10^1 + 7*10^2 + 6*10^3...
```

The other option is cast it to a char array and then just get it as a char.

Comment: i've updated the question now, something is not working like it should :/

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

After @HamZa DzCyberDeV suggestion

```
$string = '12345678'; 
echo "<pre>"; print_r (str_split($string));
```

But in mind it comes like below but your suggestion is better one.

---

If you're getting string from your function then you can use below one

```
$string = '12345678'; 
$arr = explode(",", chunk_split($string, 1, ','));
$len = count($arr);
unset($arr[$len-1]);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);
```

and output is

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 6
    [6] => 7
    [7] => 8
)
```

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV: Good to pointed it out. But `str_split()` was not came into mind first so was gone with different scenario. ;)

Comment: i've updated the question now, something is not working like it should :/

Answer (score -1):

okay what you can do is

Type cast to string with prefill 0

this is how it works

```
$sinteger =  (string)$integer;
$arrsize = 0 ; 
    for (i=strlen($sinteger), i == 0 ; i--)
    {
    arr[$arrsize]=$sinteger[i];
    $arrsize++;
    }
```

And then what is left you can prefill with zip. 
I am sure you can manage the order reverse or previous. but this is simple approach.

Comment: check out the other answers, if you cast it to a string, you can access individual character similar to java's char, but like an array in php.

Comment: @CORRUPT no it is not ... `len` should be `strlen`, In PHP we don't have to "cast" our strings `$sinteger =  (string)$integer;`, PHP does it for us and `arr[$arrsize]=$sinteger[i];` should be `$arr[$arrsize]=$sinteger[$i];` ...